# Is there a CommandParameter in XAML/WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, icommand

Can a CommandParameter be passed to a Command in WinRT? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I may have misunderstood your question entirely. If you are talking about UI commands (commands that implement the ICommand interface) you can pass parameters when you call [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand.execute.aspx). You can also test if the command and parameters are valid before executing the command by calling [CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx).

As for passing a parameter as part of a Button binding, set the [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx) property equal to the command you want the button to execute and set the [CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx) property equal to the parameter you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. WinRT applications can receive parameters through the [Application.OnLaunched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx) override.

The override receives an instance of type [LaunchActivatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.aspx) which includes the arguments.

So it *is* possible to receive arguments, the question is more about how they can be passed.

Windows Store (WinRT) applications cannot be started from the command line. If a WinRT application is associated with a file type, it can be launched by calling ShellExecute on a file. Other than that, the application cannot be started directly.

It is possible to write C++ that launches a WinRT application using the IAplicationActivationManager interface and this interface can pass parameters to the launched application. So you could create a C++ launcher executable that could be called from the command line.

For more information on how to launch an application using this interface, see the following forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/a4d2fca1-4034-4cc7-a86a-6242ce1a8b16

Comment: +1 But I do want to add that IapplicationActivationManager can be used from C# and not only from C++. You just need to define the class and interfaces using the ComImport class attribute.

Comment: If you think your answer is out of scope (not answering the question), you may delete it to avoid downvotes.